# Not redirecting to my app after signin from twitter if user account is locked

Tags: redirect, twitter, twitter-oauth

Consider a situation when users twitter account is temporarily locked ( user can get locked if he follows more than 50 users in 15 min is one of the scenario,twitter exception "To protect our users from spam and other malicious activity, this account is temporarily locked", error code - 326 ).

Now that user tries to connect his twitter account with my app, now he will redirected to twitter login page, now he enters the username and password and after that a twitter access verification page opens ( "https://twitter.com/account/access" ) , now this page asked me to change password, and then otp verification ( I tried replicating with other account and it asked me to verify phone number), so after verification , it goes to this page ("https://twitter.com/account/password-reset-complete" ) and gives option to continue to twitter but not redirected to my app.

But if user account is not locked , then its getting redirected.

I asked the same in twitter forum but got no reply.https://twittercommunity.com/t/not-redirecting-to-my-app-after-auth-and-verification-from-user-account-temp-locked-account-to-my-app/81965